# MySQL fetch 10 randomly rows where 3 predefined rows needs to be part of the results and be at the beginning

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with ID's from 1 to 20 and I need to fetch 10 rows (random), but 3 of the 10 rows are predefined and needs to be at the beginning of the result list - In one MySQL statement:

This works, but the production table contains over 500K rows:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tableName
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5,6,7) DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

I would need something like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tableName
WHERE id IN (5,6,7,*)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5,6,7) DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

... what would be the right syntax?

Comment: Have you tried executing it and checking the results?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the UNION ALL construct?

Comment: @Paddyd yes, and * isn't allowed.

Comment: @Nikhil what do you mean? The 1st statement is valid.

Comment: @ClaudioBredfeldt UNION ALL is a construct to easily combine data from two different queries. It can simply certain problems: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use statement like this:

```
SELECT
  id
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      IF(id IN (5,6,7),1,0) AS priority
      FROM tableName
  ) t
  ORDER BY priority DESC, RAND()
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Is it possible to keep the order defined in 'IN'? If I remove DESC it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: If you would like to keep the order, you should extend the IF statement to something like this IF(id=5,3,IF(id=6,2,IF(id=7,1,0)))...

Answer (score 1):

If UNION ALL is allowed, you could try something like this:

```
select id from tablename where id in (compulsary_1, compulsary_2, compulsary_3)
  order by id desc
union all
select id from tablename where id not in (compulsary_1, compulsary_2, compulsary_3)
  order by rand() limit 7
```

Comment: I see, now I got it. The framework doesn't supports UNION ALL, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around... I found this and also works:

```
SELECT id
FROM tableName
WHERE id IN (5,6,7) OR id > 0
ORDER BY FIELD(id,5,6,7) DESC, RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```